# Randomly select value 1 in list and get index

Tags: python, list

I have a list `y` of integers made up of 1's or 0's. For example,

```
 y = [1,0,0,0,0,1,0]
```

I wish to randomly select two values in the list `y` where it equals 1 and get the index of these items in the list. For example,

```
index = [0,5]
```

Comment: cool story bro.

Comment: hi @scutnex, please use a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1** - as recommended [@StefanPochmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672429/stefan-pochmann), [@rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250829/rayryeng) and [@Clayton Wahlstrom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5645103/clayton-wahlstrom).

```
index = [i for (i, j) in enumerate(y) if j]
print(random.sample(index, 2))
```

**Option 2** - My original horrible implementation...

```
import random

y = [1,0,0,0,0,1,0]

i = 0
index =[]
for each in y:
    if each == 1:
        index.append(i)
    i = i + 1
print(random.sample(index, 2))
```

Comment: You can replace the loop with a comprehension: `index = [i for (i, j) in enumerate(y) if j  == 1]`.

Comment: @rayryeng Another improvement, just enumerate with the condition `if j`

Comment: @ClaytonWahlstrom Nice. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) to create a new list containing the indices of items in `y` that equal 1, keeping only the indices. 
   `ones = [i for i, elem in enumerate(y) if elem == 1]`
2. Use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) to randomly select items from this new list, in your case, using k=2 samples: 
   `sample_ones = random.sample(ones, k=2)`

`sample_ones` is a list containing the indices for the randomly-selected elements in `y` that equal 1.